# Stretch Tabs to fill the space

Tags: c#, tabs, infragistics

How can I configure the [UltraTabControl](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinTabControl.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.UltraTabControl_members.html) to make sure that the Tab Header's fill the available space?

I have the below code that generates the following form:

```
namespace StretchThoseTabs
{
    using Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.ultraTabControl2.Tabs.AddRange(new UltraTab[]
            {
                new UltraTab(false) {Text = "General"},
                new UltraTab(false) {Text = "Advanced Options"}
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Windows Form Example]

Comment: why do you want to fill in the available space..? is there a particular reason..?

Comment: In this case, it's trying to arbitrarily match the GUI with a legacy product. I wish there was a better reason. The only other one I can think of is less mouse click precision.

Comment: that sounds odd in regards to `less mouse click precision` well unless the user is `Blind` then I guess that may make partial sense..lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `TabLayoutStyle` property.

you could set it to various options, for example the one required could be:

```
tabCtrl1.TabLayoutStyle = TabLayoutStyle.SingleRowSizeToFit;
```